# Dyson V8 keeps cutting out

Tags: vacuum-cleaner

I have already cleaned both filters and washed the 'sock' but it keeps cutting out. One thing to note that it only cuts out when I'm actively vacuum cleaning with the main hose. When I disconnect the hose the engine runs smoothly.

Comment: Have you called their customer service?

Comment: It's past warranty

Comment: There was no suggestion of asking for a warranty repair. The question was have you called customer service to see if they can help you trouble shoot the problem.

Comment: Is the hose blocked?

Comment: Battery might be dying.

Comment: @SolarMike I turned out to be so. I had to take the whole tip apart to actually see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hose is blocked.

If suction is limited, any Dyson vac will cut the motor to save overheating. Initially it will be intermittent, as that in itself can sometimes clear the obstruction, but if it continues then as it gets hotter it will switch off entirely.

You can test this by putting your hand over the end of the hose or main inlet, blocking it intentionally.

I don't know which model you are referring to [that sequence returns no hits except presumably your own question cross-posted on iFixit], but some can also get blocked where the red rectangle is marked, which can stay blocked even after emptying the bin. This, though, wouldn't stop the intermittent motor if you removed the hose.

[image]

On the battery theory, when the unit decides the battery is terminally ill, it will flash the charging lights, usually in the blue square, 32 times [yes, precisely 32*] every time you try to switch it on.]

*If you ever speak to Dyson support on the phone - which I'd recommend especially in the UK, they're very good - then they will ask you to count colours & numbers of flashes; it's how they can tell you what the fault is & what you need to do to remedy it.